# Public key is messing?

Tags: 14.04, updates

I get this error when I update the system:

`W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 241FE6973B765FAE`

is there something to work it out ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import the Public Key with the following command. Then update:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 241FE6973B765FAE
```

Comment: I got the following error: gpg: requesting key 3B765FAE from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 241FE6973B765FAE not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

Comment: Above answer is only applicable for @Mohammad

Comment: OK, so what the solution for my error >> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 241FE6973B765FAE